# Update, Insert and Delete a large MySQL from a large CSV file

Tags: java, python, mysql, database, csv

We receive around 10 million lines of data in CSV file each day.  This CSV file contains location and price data for around 5,000 products.

Sometimes the CSV is updated and sometimes it remains the same. The data in the CSV is the source of truth (e.g. the data that we always want to use inside our apps).

Here is a snippet from the CSV:

```
UUID,Location,Price
AAA,Melbourne,21.96
AAA,Sydney,32.43
BBB,Melbourne,23.43
BBB,Adelaide,32.43
```

We need to store the up to date data inside out MySQL database.

Here is an example of how this data needs to be stored:

Location_Data:

```
ID,ProductID,Location,Price
1,1,Melbourne,21.96
2,1,Sydney,32.43
3,2,Melbourne,23.43
4,2,Adelaide,32.43
```

Product:

```
ID,UUID (and other fields not relevant to this question)
1,AAA
2,BBB
```

For the initial import we are using MySQL `LOAD DATA IN FILE`.  This is quite fast. Here is the process:

- We fetch all the products from the database
- We match each line of the CSV to the product in the database
- We then we generate a new CSV file that we can directly import to the location_data table.

The updated CSV file might contain new locations, updated prices or locations that no longer exist.  We need to `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` in all of these scenarios.

Moving forward to the issue... We are struggling to solve how we can quickly update the database when we receive a new CSV file that has been changed.

Unfortunately we have only come up with two options that aren't working for us:

- Fetch the data from the database and check it against the CSV file (line by line). This is very slow to fetch that much data and then again it is very slow to compare it to the CSV.
- Delete all the database data and re-import. Unfortunately this isn't possible (we need to keep a history of the changes made to the data. We loose that history when we delete and insert the whole data set).

Any suggestions on how we can manage to speed it up?

Comment: So if I am understanding it correctly, your CSV file which is generated every day is your source of truth. Can you elaborate with an example when do you update entries in your database and when you insert new entries as per your CSV file? Can there be a case when you inserted 2 rows yesterday and you get 2 entirely new rows in your CSV today which will make the total number of rows in your DB to 4? Or do you not care about the 2 entries made yesterday as they are not in today's CSV file?

Comment: Table structure and sample data from DB and CSV would help to understand the question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have updated the original question with example data. I hope this clarifies the issue.

Comment: Why not make a stage table with the columns date, UUID, location, price, dynamiclly set the date in the LOAD DATA, And compare the data with a self join to see what is missing within a stored procedure to limit queries between the client and server and insert, update or delete from the real table based on the compared data? Make sure to also make a index on the UUID.. This method requires you to to keep the data from the previous data only the rest you can delete..

Comment: @Raymond Thanks for your suggestion.  Im concerned that the comparison between the staging table and the real data table will be very slow (it will be a comparison of around 10 million rows). Perhaps I am not understanding your suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding your suggestion?  indeed you do keep a old set from the old day and load the new data with LOAD DATA for new day in the stage table.. And compare the UUID with a self join to get the missing or new onces within a stored procedure and import/update also within that SP

Comment: When doing that on a index MySQL should be able to do a 20 million compare (between two 10 million datasets) without anny trouble at all..

Comment: "we need to keep a history of the changes made to the data" - What does that mean? Do you also amintaining a version table?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel We need to keep a history of changes so that the users can see the current price and the previous ones. Current we handle this is having a trigger that updates another table whenever there is a change to one of the values. The user interface then shows the history using that seperate table.

Comment: @user1875694 There are still some open questions? What would be fast enough for you? What would be not acceptable? How many rows (approx.) do change daily? How long does it take to LOAD the CSV file? How long did it take to add ProductIDs (from DB) to the CSV file?